# Pre-Populating a Facebook Send Dialogue with multiple names

Tags: facebook, send, sendmessage

I want to give my app user the ability to pre-select a number of friends and then present him with a 'send dialogue' one step later pre-populated with all these names for his approval and ability to click send. How do I get approved to do this currently it looks like I can only prepopulate with one name. Do I have to apply to get white listed? if so how?

Any help appreciated

Rupert